# Last try for guesses and Try/Except in Guess The Number game

Tags: python, try-except

I am a newbie and need help to include a "last try" phrase after 4 of the 5 tries and a try-except element. I searched through past questions but I am still stuck with this code:

```
import random

random_number = random.randrange(0,20)
print(random_number)

print("Guess a number in the range 0-20. You have five tries.")
guess = False

while guess == False:
    user_input = int(input("Your guess? "))
if user_input == random_number:
    guess = True
    print("Congratulations! Your guess is correct! It is " + str(random_number) + "!")
elif user_input > random_number:
    print("The number is too high.")
elif user_input < random_number:
    print("The number is too low.")
elif user_input < 5:
    try:
        guess = int(input("This is your last guess: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry. Your guesses are incorrect. The right answer is " + str(random_number) + ".")

print("End of program")
```

Comment: A few things: 1) `try` will only fail if the user inputs something that cannot be interpreted as an integer; it has nothing to do with the correct answer in this case. 2) Your if statements are not indented. As a result, the while loop has no way of exiting. 3) You seem to be using the user's input guess to count how many times they have guessed. Instead, you should initialize something like `num_tries = 0`, then do `while num_tries < 5` (at the end of the while loop, increment `num_tries`), and if the user guesses the correct answer in less tries, use `break` to exit.

Comment: Why are you comparing the user's guess to 5? You need a separate counter variable to keep track of the number of attempts... (or just use a `for` loop...)

Answer (score 1):

OK
I got it

This is updated one!

```py
import random

def main():
    random_number = random.randrange(0,20) 
    print(random_number) 

    print("Guess a number in the range 0-20. You have five tries.") 

    number_of_tries = 0
    guess = False  
    while guess == False and number_of_tries < 5: 
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1
        print()
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Your guess? ")) 
        except ValueError: 
            print("Your guess cannot be converted into an integer") 
        if user_input == random_number: 
            guess = True 
            print("Congratulations! Your guess is correct! It is " + str(random_number) + "!") 
        elif user_input > random_number: 
            print("The number is too high.") 
        elif user_input < random_number: 
            print("The number is too low.") 
    
    if (number_of_tries == 5):
        print()
        print("This is your last try")
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Your guess? ")) 
        except ValueError: 
            print("Your guess cannot be converted into an integer")
        print()


    if (number_of_tries == 5 and guess == False):
        print("Your guesses are incorrect. The right answer is " + str(random_number))
        print("End of program")
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are very kind. I changed it but it still doesn't work though...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Check the new one :) it works!

Answer (score -1):

Got a little help...

import random

```
def main():
  random_number = random.randrange(0,20) 
  print(random_number) 

  print("Guess a number in the range 0-20. You have five tries.") 

  number_of_tries = 0
  guess = False  
  while guess == False and number_of_tries < 5: 
    number_of_tries += 1

    if (number_of_tries == 5):
      print("This is your last try")

    try:
      user_input = int(input("Your guess? ")) 
    except ValueError: 
      print("Your guess cannot be converted into an integer")
      continue


    if user_input == random_number: 
      guess = True 
      print("Congratulations! Your guess is correct! It is " + str(random_number) + "!") 
    elif user_input > random_number: 
      print("The number is too high.") 
    elif user_input < random_number: 
      print("The number is too low.") 


if (number_of_tries == 5 and guess == False):
     print("Your guesses are incorrect. The right answer is " + str(random_number))

  print("End of program")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```